# Drupal hook_user stop execution

Tags: drupal, hook

I need to use Drupal 6's "hook_user" to update a 3rd party API whenever a user updates their profile.

Therefore I use the 'update' operation.  The problem I am facing is that I just cannot see how I can stop execution if the 3rd party API update fails.

I.e. the user updates their username, but if the API fails, prevent Drupal from updating the local record.

```
function myhooks_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category) {

    switch ( $op )
    {

        case 'update':

            if ( FALSE === updateAPI($data) )
            {
                drupal_set_message("Cannot update user information", "error", false);

                return false; 
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

At the moment, the return false doesn't stop execution.

Comment: If you add a watchdog() call inside the if statement, is it getting into that statement? I'm not sure hook_user can be used in this manner.

Comment: Yeah, it is getting into the function ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to stop execution.

You should be able to overwrite `$edit`, with what's in the db. That way there wont be any change. I haven't tried this out, but it should work just fine.

Why do you want to do this anyways? You could just add a row in the db, and update the profile at a later time with cron instead, to avoid frustrated users that need to do the same edit over and over.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I want to do it to maintain an external database, so that for example, when a user updates their information, the external db gets updated.  Therefore, if the external update fails, I want to stop Drupal updating.  I think I may use the 'validate' operation instead.

Comment: @JonB unless it's absolutely critical that your external DB is in sync with your Drupal db at all times, I would suggest creating a cron job as a backup instead that will try sync the db's until you succeed. It's normal to have cron jobs to run every 5 mins, so you should be fine. It's a lot more usable for the user, and you don't want to discourage users not keeping their profiles up to date. It's also fairly easy to create a cron job like that with hook_cron.